# Is the ASP.NET Web Deployment Project alive?

Tags: asp.net, web-deployment-project

The [latest link](http://blogs.iis.net/msdeploy/archive/2008/05/13/web-deployment-tool-beta-1-go-live-just-released.aspx) I can find is from last may and that's Beta 1.  Did Microsoft give up on this?  I realize they are just basically MSBuild templates, but curious nonetheless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ***hope*** they're not still alive.

We probably used them improperly so it's probably our own fault, but they caused us ***huge*** issues when we wanted to update just a portion of our site.  The supposed benefits of using web site deployment projects never paid off for us and just caused more problems than they were worth.

***Edit***

Drats. They're still alive.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en

Comment: Interesting, I've always done all or nothing deployment, so haven't had that problem.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: I'm not really sure how these are a problem, if you don't want to do full site deployments then just don't use them - simple as that. For situations where you do want a nice neat deployable unit they are brilliant.

Comment: That may be, but given how easy it is to publish from Visual Studio, I still haven't seen the benefit to these.  The problems they solve can be just as easly solved by making some simple changes in config files, etc, and in my personal opinion, the web deployment projects just add unnecessary complexity.  I like things simple, I guess, and while these aren't rocket science, it's just one more thing to have to deal with.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Web Deployment projects are @ http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=89f2c4f5-5d3a-49b6-bcad-f776c6edfa63&displayLang=en

Comment: Now a bit late, but I found them very useful. I used the web.config section replacements along with separate TFS builds for each environment. This meant that I could auto-deploy on non-critical systems and it saved me a LOT of time. Also the aspx compilation was very handy.

Comment: Yeah, this is an old answer, and the truth is, Microsoft does a pretty good job of making improvements with each new release.  I haven't gone back to look at what's available now, so my cynical, biased answer may well be completely wrong for current tools.

Answer (score 11):

[Visual Studio® 2010 Web Deployment Projects - RTW](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=89f2c4f5-5d3a-49b6-bcad-f776c6edfa63&displaylang=en)

Web Deployment Projects are going forward in VS2010 - which is good news since web packages do not support Website projects

Comment: I saw that today. I guess MS changed their mind after they said they weren't going to continue on it.  I've abandoned it for now anyway, just using straight msbuild for packaging.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the web deployment projects, but here's something that's definitely alive: [Web Deployment Tool (MS Deploy)](http://forums.iis.net/1144.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the link, looks like MS Deploy or "Web Deployment Tool" is something to check out.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that they are packing this into Visual Studio 2010 . See http://blogs.msdn.com/webdevtools/archive/2009/06/28/vs2010-beta1-web-application-project-database-package-and-smo-options.aspx

Comment: Looks like it, thanks, but there's certainly no confusion in having things named "Web Deployment Project" and "Web Deployment Tool" is there? ;-)  Clear as mud.

Answer (score 1):

The response from Microsoft:

> Web Deployment Projects is not
>   currently planned to be part of VS
>   2010...  As WDP is out of band we have not yet started planning on it as the
>   team is focused on working on VS 2010
>   at this point...

Looks like they've definitely shifted their focus onmsdeploy and "web packages."

Answer (score 0):

I second David stratton - these things are the definition of half-baked. Good ideas wrapped in poor execution, the best thing I can say about them is that they aren't InstallShield.

Comment: I hear ya, I don't understand the Visual Studio/IIS focus on deploying from tools or building web app installers and the like (as opposed to using script based/automated deployment).  I liked that the Web Deployment Projects were msbuild (script) based.  But, yes, it was certainly raw when I last used it.  That's why I was wondering what happened, and if it ever went beyond beta.